# Converting VARCHAR2 to DATE in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-arithmetic

There is a column 'A' with Data Type as `VARCHAR2` in PLSQL. It can contain values like 120, 60, 78 etc. These values basically denote minutes.

Now there is another column 'B' with data type as `DATE`. I need to make the following comparison in a `WHERE` clause of a `SELECT` statement-

```
WHERE SYSDATE - B > A
```

How do I manage the data types here so that this comparison can be made?

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language. This seems like a question about SQL, not PL/SQL programming.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
where sysdate - B > A / (24 * 60)
```

because difference of two `DATE` datatype values (which is `SYSDATE - B`) is number of **days** between them, so you have to "convert" `A` (i.e. *minutes*) into *number of days*, so - divide it by `(24 * 60)` as day has `24` hours, and every hour has `60` minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You may use explicit interval specification that is readable in code with [`numtodsinterval`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NUMTODSINTERVAL.html#GUID-5A7392A8-7976-4465-8839-A65EFF1A80B6):

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     sysdate as dt
>     , to_char(level*10, 'tm9') as dt_offset
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 10
> )
> select
>   a.*
>   , sysdate + numtodsinterval(to_number(dt_offset, '999999999'), 'MINUTE') as date_new
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> DT                  | DT_OFFSET | DATE_NEW           
> :------------------ | :-------- | :------------------
> 2021-07-14 13:17:50 | 10        | 2021-07-14 13:27:50
> 2021-07-14 13:17:50 | 20        | 2021-07-14 13:37:50
> 2021-07-14 13:17:50 | 30        | 2021-07-14 13:47:50
> 2021-07-14 13:17:50 | 40        | 2021-07-14 13:57:50
> 2021-07-14 13:17:50 | 50        | 2021-07-14 14:07:50
> 2021-07-14 13:17:50 | 60        | 2021-07-14 14:17:50
> 2021-07-14 13:17:50 | 70        | 2021-07-14 14:27:50
> 2021-07-14 13:17:50 | 80        | 2021-07-14 14:37:50
> 2021-07-14 13:17:50 | 90        | 2021-07-14 14:47:50
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8196d424c9405d35d07232b66a8945d)*